# Client/Server TLS Authentication in Go

Tags: ssl, go, tls1.2

What's the easiest way to get TCP Client/Server authentication via TLS/Certs/Keys in Go?

That is, I have a TCP server, and when a new client tries to connect to it, it should receive a certificate/key from the Server to allow it to connect again in the future without re-authenticating (or at least until the certificate expires). Both the client and the server should authenticate the other. OpenSSL isn't an option to create keys as the clients will be cross platform (Windows/macOS/Linux). Essentially, the server should only accept connections from known clients, and authorize new clients as needed (the clients can have some sort of known secret when installed).

Here's what I think the general flow is (correct me if I'm wrong)

Server: Get Cert/Key pair --> if they don't exist, create them --> listen on port --> receive connection --> verify Certificate is valid --> if not, reject --> if it is, continue to do what the server is supposed to do

Client: Get cert/key pair --> if they don't exist (i.e just installed), request from the server (Signed by the server) --> continue to connect as normal

This is still in the planning phase and open to all suggestions!

Thanks!

Comment: Since your clients/servers will need to authenticate each other why not just use server and client certificates signed by a known CA? Then all you need is an existing library (eg: grpc with SSL) and do mutual auth. This is way safer than trying to control a shared secret.

Comment: @Marc What's the easiest way to request a certificate from the server if I were to go with a self signed CA?

Comment: https://github.com/levigross/go-mutual-tls seems like the right answer

Comment: you don't request a certificate from the server, the client should already have a cert and key. If you're distributing secrets with your client, might as well go for that rather than try to do your own authentication scheme that returns a certificate.